# DatePicker and TimePicker on DialogPreference

Tags: android, datepicker, android-preferences, android-theme, timepicker

I have a PreferenceFragment that loads preferences by calling addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_main);

In side the preferences_main.xml file I have a custom preference called TimePreference which extends DialogPreference. TimePreference contains nothing but a TimePicker (have also tried DatePicker). When displayed the TimePicker is now a different format. Instead of being a spinner, it is the version with EditText views and up/down arrows. The real problem is those arrows are white and the text is white, all on a white background dialog.

If I put a TimePicker on an activity, it is the themed spinner style.

I cannot find out why this only happens on a DialogPreference and not on the activity. Its like it loses all styling.

My base theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light, I have tried a couple others with the same result.

Edit: My minSdkVersion is 11 and the target is 19

Anyone have any ideas?

```
public class TestPreference extends DialogPreference {

Button btn;
TimePicker tp;

public TestPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView() {
    tp = new TimePicker(getContext().getApplicationContext());
    return tp;
}
```

}

[image: TimePicker in DialogPreference]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Application context which does not hold any information about theme/style chose for your application.

Try changing the initialization of `TimePicker` as below and see if it works:

```
tp = new TimePicker(getContext());
```

Moreover, when creating an instance of your `TestPreference`, pass your activity's reference in its constructor, for example: `YourActivity.this`.

Comment: I was just trying that before eclipse crashed and it seemed to be working. I will let you know more in a few.

Comment: Also TestPreference is being created from the preferences xml so how can I pass my activity's reference to it?

Comment: ahh, then simply stick to what I said for initializing TimePicker.

Comment: waqaslam, that was the solution... The style was still different that the norm and that was because the style in values-14 was different. I changed that style and got the expected layout. The issue with the font and arrows being white was resolved by removing the .getApplicationContext(). Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver. @waqaslam do you think you could help me here http://goo.gl/MAjgTh